# Authenticating a Google Drive service account owned by a Django app?

Tags: django, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm new to Django and relatively new to OAuth. I'm building a Django app that's basically aiming to be a wrapper around Google Drive that implements tagging and user permissions. A few users who have important documents share them with the service account, and then the app provides a nice interface.

I'm generally confused about how to organize this, since Django seems to have many, many moving parts.

The app needs to almost constantly be authenticated with and talking to the Google Drive API.

Where does this authentication go? A model? Is it part of a site template that gets inserted on every page?

Answer (score 2):

Here's [sample app](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/django_sample) of integrating Django with OAuth2. You especially want to take a look at [this file](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/django_sample) where it saves user credential using Storage class. There is also [a documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django) with better explanation about how OAuth flow with Storage works in Django.

To answer your question, you would want to define credential at Django user profile in order to save it easily associated with users. Also, your OAuth flow (creating auth url and authenticating) works at view.

Comment: Just make sure that you get a refresh token, and use the refresh token to periodically update your access token.

Comment: Right, I've seen that, but I'm not trying to associate the app with users' Google Drive accounts -- the app itself has an account, which it needs to talk to all the time.

So I guess that in order to do that, I authenticate the app once and get a refresh token. Then I make a function in a view that authenticates the app with Google Drive every time it loads a page that needs to access the documents it has?